# How can I echo double quotes around text

Tags: command-line, bash

How can I get the double quotes to show for 1 second and ready?

```
echo -e " test.sh ""1 second"" "ready""
```

Comment: use `echo -e 'test.sh ""1 second"" "ready"'`  (or whatever you're after, ie. replace the outside quotes with single-quotes)

Comment: Consider using `printf` instead of `echo` - see for example [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 2):

If your outer quotes were single quotes, the *inner* double-quotes would be treated as part of the text.

```
guiverc@d7050-next:~/uwn/issues/825$   echo -e 'test.sh ""1 second"" "ready"'
test.sh ""1 second"" "ready"
```

Adjust as required.

Comment: there are many ways you can accomplish this (eg. what Terrance describes is what I'll often do myself)... but my first *comment* reply was left partially because it was the easiest/fastest as I was focused on the publish of [UWN 825](https://ubuntu-news.org/2024/02/05/ubuntu-weekly-newsletter-issue-825/) at the time, and switching of two characters; `"` to `'` being quick to test & show (ie. copy/paste result)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `echo -e` which means `enable interpretation of backslash escapes` you can escape `\` the quotes as well so they show up as actual quotes.

```
echo -e "test.sh \"1 second\" \"ready\""
```

Example:

```
$ echo -e "test.sh \"1 second\" \"ready\""
test.sh "1 second" "ready"
```